# Margins between images with float: left

Tags: css, css-float, margin

I want to put 8 images all together in 2 rows, the problem is that below the images a margin of 5px is generated. You can see [in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73d9m89b/) that the images are in a `<div>` with *position:relative*, that's because inside I'm going to put a hidden box with additional information (it works, but I didn't add it to the fiddle to not complicate things).

Thanks for your help!

```css
.projects{
    overflow:auto;
}

.project{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.project img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to vertical alignment. An easy way to resolve this is to specify `vertical-align: top;` on your `img` elements:

```css
.project img {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/73d9m89b/1/).

Comment: Thanks James! You were of great help, but I'm trying to understand the reasons behind this and I don't get it... how this happens? Thanks in advance!